# How to force Ubuntu(Wayland) to output "Broadcast RGB: FULL" to a HDMI output?

Tags: ubuntu, wayland

I'm using intel 620 GPU and currently running Ubuntu 19.10/Wayland.

The system have an eDP monitor and a HDMI monitor.(Basic laptop + monitor setup).

On Windows this is easy:

```
1) Configure full RGB range in intel graphics driver control panel.

2) Or, use YUV output because my monitor supports YUV and YUV is ambiguously limited range.
```

On X.org it's doable:
`xrandr --output HDMI1 --set "Broadcast RGB" "Full"`

On Wayland this seems plain impossible.

Running through some bug reports, the situation seems to be, in my understanding, that HDMI is targeting TV and TV mostly accepts limited RGB so i915 defaults to limited RGB range.

So, it seems like I have very limited options for this combo of hardware:

```
1) Run Windows and use VM if/when I need Ubuntu (high power and memory overhead)

2) Run Ubuntu with X (this will not last forever)

3) Run Ubuntu with Wayland with analog VGA(VGA for 1920x1080@60Hz is somewhat OK, but not more).
4) Run Ubuntu with Wayland with non-TV resolution
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the instructions from [Quick Tip: Setting the Color Space Value in Wayland](https://www.brad-x.com/2017/08/07/quick-tip-setting-the-color-space-value-in-wayland/) by Brad T. Laue, I came up with the following solution (sort of):

1. Install `libdrm-tests` and run `proptest`.
2. For the monitor that has this issue, identify connector number and also the number of the "Broadcast RGB" property.
3. Switch to TTY console and run:

```
/usr/bin/proptest -M i915 -D /dev/dri/card0 <ID_of_connector> connector <ID_of_property> <value>
```

Try `<value>` of 1 or 2. The result is instant. Your screen should go black for a second, then the black background of the console should be darker than before.

4. Make this permanent by editing GDM3 service configuration to run this command before GDM3 starts. Make a backup:

```
sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service /lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service.bak
```

Then edit the file with **nano**:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/gdm3.service
```

5. In the `[Service]` section, add before any other entries:

```
ExecStartPre=-/usr/bin/proptest -M i915 -D /dev/dri/card0 74 connector 76 1
```

This is the command for my system. Do **not** forget the `-` before the command. This instructs **systemd** to continue in case the command fails (non-zero return code).

6. Save and reboot.

I made a detailed post about this "washed out colors" issue on my blog: [Set full RGB to HDMI monitor on Ubuntu](https://www.onetransistor.eu/2021/08/hdmi-picture-quantization-range-linux.html). The problem I have now is that this fix stopped working out of a sudden, without me changing anything. The command fails on boot with status `243/CREDENTIALS`, but it works after I am logged in and issue a restart of GDM3 from terminal.